# Do electric push activated screwdrivers exist?

Tags: tools, powertools, screwdriver

I am looking for a screwdriver. I want it to be powered (electric, cordless). I want it to not be based on a trigger mechanism (in order to reduce repetitive motion strain). I want it to screw (or unscrew with a switch) based on pressure applied (i.e. pushing down on the screw). I want the tips to be magnetic to grab the screw. Does such a tool exist?

Comment: "Shop for me" type questions, are typically considered off topic here.  Try [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/), [Google Shopping](http://www.google.com/prdhp), etc.

Comment: @Tester101 I understand that, but this is more of a "does the tool I am thinking of exist" question imho - which I thought was legit

Comment: It looks to me like you're supplying a list of attributes you'd like in a product, and asking where you can buy it.  That sounds exactly like you're asking the community to shop for you. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Tester101 I've removed the statement "where can I buy it" does that help?

Comment: In my mind, no. But as always, I'll let the community decide.

Comment: If you disagree, you can always ask for further clarification on [meta](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/), or in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/home-improvement)

Answer (score 2):

Black & Decker GYRO might be worth a look

http://www.blackanddecker.com/power-tools/BDCS40G.aspx